# What would a 1940s audience have understood from the phrase "wired for sound"?

Tags: etymology, american-english, phrase-meaning, history

[Another question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/263529/) asks for the meaning and origin of the phrase "wound [i.e., 'winded'] for sound." The obvious conclusion over there is that "wound for sound" is likely a rhyming variation on the older phrase "wired for sound." There's also general consensus that "wired for sound" at some point had the slang meaning of "high on amphetamines," leading to the modern sense of the word "wired."

[Someone on PhraseOrigins](https://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/25/messages/966.html) points to the Cliff Richard single "Wired for Sound" (1981) and claims it has something to do with portable music players (as in, headphone wires)... but frankly even Cliff Richard's song isn't about portable music in *particular*. (["I like small speakers, I like tall speakers..."](https://genius.com/Cliff-richard-wired-for-sound-lyrics))

Also, the phrase itself goes *way* far back. I first encountered it [in Irving Berlin's lyrics](https://www.lyricsplayground.com/alpha/songs/t/thisisthearmysoundtrack.html) from the movie [*This is the Army* (1943)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0036430/):

> When the night is clear, and the bombardier
>   Drops a bomb that's **wired for sound**,
>   How I yearn to return, with my head in the clouds,
>   To the one I love on the ground.

Actually, a Google Books search (which sadly I cannot figure out how to link to, but you can click the search links [at the bottom of the Ngram Viewer page](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wired+for+sound&year_start=1890&year_end=1940)) shows pretty conclusively that the phrase comes from *movie theaters* being "wired for sound", as in "having wiring installed for the purpose of playing talking pictures." Which I *think* means I've answered half of my own question.

The other half is, what was the original slang meaning of "wired for sound", such as in the song lyrics above? In that context, does it just mean "a bomb that **explodes loudly**," with a subtle positive connotation toward modern technology? or was there a more specific meaning that 1940s audiences would have picked up on?

I specifically think I might be missing something because I know vaguely that some bombs [have wires attached](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wire-guided_missile) and some bombs [make sounds as they fall](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/2686/did-world-war-ii-era-bombs-actually-whistle).

Comment: To me, the use of *wired for sound* is simply an expression that means *built for noise*. Just as in the case of the "newfangled talkies," so to in the case of the bomb—which is going to make a large noise. Or a baby that's "wired for sound" to keep you up at night . . .

Comment: Irving Berlin's reference is pretty straight forward. Acoustic triggers were one type of proximity fuse. "[The British used a Rochelle salt microphone and a piezoelectric device to trigger a relay to detonate the projectile or bomb's explosive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proximity_fuze)."

Comment: @Phil Sweet ...acoustic triggers did "wire for sound", but, were passive devices, and, most importantly, were extremely secret.  any certain reference to such a device in a song would have had the song writer and performer in detention.

Comment: Hollywood song writer Irving Berlin, composing song lyrics in 1943, could not possibly have known any of the technical details of Allied proximity fuses used in World War 2, because all such devices were classified top secret. Nor, more importantly, could movie audiences have known about the classified details of those fuses. Therefore, including a reference to such devices in a song would make no sense. So whatever the lyrics in that song refer to, this cannot be a reference to a secret military development about which the movie-going public knew nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question resolves most of its own issues.
Wiring motion picture theaters for sound had happened in the decade before WW2. That conversion was fresh in the minds of many.

What Irving Berlin might have meant about a **bomb that's wired for sound**  was probably not much, except to get a rhyme with **ground**. Ariel bombs during WW2 were typically fin stabilized, with the air flowing over the fins creating something of a whistle. Falling bombs were not silent.
An additional **wired for sound** in WW2  was the German [*Stuka* dive bomber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junkers_Ju_87). This plane itself was [**wired for sound**.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2JdcyGGby0Y) Anyone watching a sound newsreel might mistake the airplane's siren for its bomb. The notion of screaming death from above had been established by 1943.

This is a good question that mostly answers itself.

Comment: The question is if newsreels (+1) with sound prior to 1940 had 'bomb-sounding-bombs' in them (which isn't really ontopic here). Stukas came out in 1936... so I guess it's possible. [citation from <1940 needed]

Comment: I heard an interview with a songwriter recently where smoke asked what some of his lyrics meant; the reply was, "they don't mean anything, it's a _song_."

Comment: @Mazura ...I added some 1940 footage as a link for the Stuka.

Comment: @James Random ......"they don't mean anything, it's a song."... that has always been my understanding.

Comment: Stukas were first employed in action in the Spanish Civil War in the 1930s. Long before September 1939, it was well known that they were fitted with a siren which made a terrifying shrieking sound as they dived, which was completely independent of the noise made by the bombs they dropped. This siren was a German terror-weapon, designed to cause panic among civilians and enemy ground troops. Stukas failed as a weapon when Britain entered the war: they were 100mph slower than British fighter aircraft, so were easy to shoot down, thus this aspect ended in 1940 when the Stuka was withdrawn.

Comment: By 1943, when Irving Berlin was composing the lyrics for his song, the Stuka had long since been retired from service by the Germans. If the lyrics do in fact refer to aerial combat in World War 2, then they certainly do not refer to the Stuka, which didn't feature in any prominent combat roles after its failure in the Battle of Britain in 1940.

Answer (score 0):

I agree, it came from theaters.  Thus, by the 1940s, lots of people would have understood that.

BTW, there is a fascinating little area of understanding how people conceptualized things and had phrases related to them before we had current technologies.  For example, many severely paranoid schizophrenics believe that their thoughts can be read or altered by others through electromagnetic radiation, thus leading to putting foil around their heads to prevent it.  It has a coinage now, 'tin-hat', meaning paranoid - like "isn't all that worrying you do about what Facebook does with your data getting awfully tin-hat?".  But, in 1700, what did people with that sort of problem think or do, and what phrases have been lost describing them|?

Comment: In the past, unexplained aerial phenomena (or UFOs) were attributed to angels rather than aliens. So, hearing voices would probably have been attributed to demons (or gods) and so the equivalent of "tin[foil] hat" would probably have been some sort of religious imagery.

Comment: I suggest this is all largely backwards and "wired for sound" does now and always has dealt with recording, not play-back… ie, the studio, not the theatre.

Comment: That is totally not an answer to the question at all, so I can't bring myself to upvote it; but you might enjoy https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_loom

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin: I initially assumed the same as you (something like "wired for sound" = "wearing a wire"), but Google Books proved me wrong. Follow the search links [at the bottom of Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wired+for+sound&year_start=1890&year_end=1940) for my evidence.

Comment: Might we please remember, the first “talkie” feature film was *The Jazz Singer*, in 1927.

Do you think if all those years later, anyone gave a rat’s whisker, his theatre would still be in business?

Comment: The human brain does not use electromagnetic induction, nor any other magnetic effects, in order to function. It is based on an electro-chemical process that does not utilise electro-magnetism. Loonies who wrap their heads in tin-foil to prevent the non-existant electro-magnetic waves from leaking out are wasting their time, because their brain doesn't generate any.